# Setup a remote client with Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote, macos

I'm working on video production for one of our school TV shows; we have Mac pros set up for editing with Final Cut.
It's always a problem that I couldn't edit from outside the school, as there is still not enough time to edit footages fast enough for a story.

I asked one of the IT administrators if I could set up remote software on the Macs, he declined, but agreed if I could set up something without interfering with administrator permissions on the Macs.

I would like to know if I could use Rasberry pi as a gateway and connect to the Mac like this:
Mac (HDMI) -> Rasberry Pi -> My PC
My PC -> (Send control via USB) Rasberry Pi -> (Redirects USB operations) Mac

Comment: I do not understand this sequence: `Mac (HDMI) -> Rasberry Pi -> My PC My PC -> (Send control via USB) Rasberry Pi -> (Redirects USB operations) Mac`. Do you want to have two RasPis, one connected to a Mac, the other connected to a PC? Where the RasPis, Macs and PC are located? At school? At home? Remote anywhere on the Internet? Where is the source of the video movies that should be modified on Macs? How to connect to it?

Comment: Currently your question reads as if you plan to install an HDMI cable from a Mac in your school to an RPi somewhere else, which sounds absurd.

Comment: Yes, I would like to connect the raspberry pi as a remote client that receives HDMI input from the mac. when I connect to the pi, I send USB input to the pi remotely, and it redirects it to the mac.

Comment: And it does, but that's the best way I can think of without interfering with the permissions on the macs.

Comment: How about using Teamviewer? It does not need to be installed, it can start off the bat after downloading and is way easier than your suggested setup. You only need the Mac running and unlocked.